# Doubt in quotient rule for derivatives.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I'm reading Rudin, and in theorem 5.3 he states that:

Suppose $f,g$ are real functions on $[a,b]$ that are differentiable at $x \in [a,b]$. Then $f/g$ is differentiable at $x$, provided that $g(x) \neq 0$ and

$$\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)'(x) = \frac{g(x)f'(x) - g'(x)f(x)}{g^2(x)}$$

Following Rudin's convention, the domain of $f/g$ are those point $x$ of $[a,b]$ where $g(x) \neq 0$.

However, Rudin's definition of differentiability only mentions the cases where $f$ is differentiable on an open or closed interval.

How do I interpret/solve this?

For completeness, here is the relevant definition:

Let $f$ be defined (and real-valued) on $[a,b]$. For any $x \in [a,b]$, form the quotient $$\phi(t) = \frac{f(t) - f(x)}{t-x}\quad (a < t <b, t \neq x)$$ and define $$f'(x) = \lim_{t \to x} \phi(t)$$

Maybe I'm just worrying too much..

Comment: I can't see a problem here: the definition of derivative doesn't use the quotient rule (which logically comes *later* than the definition of derivative).

Comment: He states that $f/g$ is differentiable while the domain of this function isn't necessarily an interval, something he asks for in his own definition.

Comment: You could break up the interval at the points where $g(x)=0$. So you would have a set of intervals: $(a,x_1)$ , $(x_1 , x_2)$, ... , $(x_n , b)$.

Answer (score 2):

> **Theorem:** Let $g$ be a continuous function on an open interval $(a,b)$. Suppose that $c \in (a,b)$ satisfies $g(c) \neq 0$. Then there exists $d,e$ such that $a < d < c < e < b$ with the property that $g(x) \neq 0$ for every $x \in (d,e)$.

In other words, if $c$ is a point in the domain of $f/g$, then there is an open interval containing $c$ which is contained in the domain of $f/g$.

Comment: Thus I have to consider the differentiability of the quotient on such an interval?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is that $[a,b]\setminus\{x:g(x)=0\}$
may not be an open or closed interval, and Rudin's definitions
only encompass differentiability on such sets. If so, so much the
worse for Rudin's definitions.

There is no real problem here: if $x_0\in [a,b]$ and $g(x_0)\ne0$
then there is $d>0$ such that $g$ is continuous on $I=(x_0-d,x_0+d)
\cap[a,b]$.
That will be an interval containing $x_0$ on which $f/g$ is defined,
and on which $f/g$ will turn out to be differentiable. Whatever
$(f/g)'(x_0)$ means, it should certainly equal the value of $(f/g)'$,
as defined on $I$, at $x_0$.

Comment: My question for you is: then what does $(f/g)'$ mean here? I can agree that it should equal the value as defined on I.